# Macbook keyboard incorrect mappings

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, firmware

My gut is telling me this is a hardware problem, but I thought I'd ask here just in case.

I just got a 'new' refurbished Macbook Pro Retina 2013. Pressing the 'i' key inputs an 'o', and pressing the '8' key inputs a '9'. As far as I can tell, these are the only two keys whose mappings are incorrect. I can plug in a USB keyboard and it works just fine.

Is there a way to reinstall the keyboard firmware on a Mac to test for that? Or am I hosed, with the only option being to send it back for (further) repair?

Comment: If an external keyboard works fine, that's a pretty good indicator that the internal one is damaged.

Answer (score 2):

I would reset both your NVRAM and your SMC. See below for instructions.

**Reset your NVRAM**

Newer Macs use Non-Volatile Random-Access Memory (NVRAM). It may be worth you resetting this. Here’s how to:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. **Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys.** You have to make sure you press these keys before the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again and you here the startup chime.
4. **Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.**

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. mouse speed, time and date/timezone, etc).

**Reset the SMC**

Your computer's System Management Controller (SMC) can also be reset. To reset this on your particular MacBook Pro, here’s what you do:

1. Shut down your computer
2. Keep the power cable **plugged in**.
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the left side of the keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.

After doing both these, let us know how you go.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I have already done both of those things, to no avail.

Comment: What happens when you start it in Safe Mode? You can do this by holding down the Shift key while it's booting up. Does it work fine then?

Comment: The problem persists in Safe Mode, and when I boot to Repair mode. I am going to try a reinstall of the OS.

Comment: Sounds like a fair way to proceed, especially since it's happening in Safe Mode. Also, if you've just bought it, then _refurbished_ Macs will have warranty. How much will depend on where you are and who it was bought from. Either way, if the re-installation doesn't solve the problem, time to take it back.